# Count related models and limit using Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a working Sequelize query that get models including the count of related models in this way:

```js
    const elements = await ElementsModel.findAll({
      attributes: {
        include: [[Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("related.id")), "related_total"]]
      },
      include: [
        {
          model: RelatedModel,
          attributes: [],
        }
      ],
      group: ['elements.id']
    });
```

The query works great, but now I need to include an `offset` and `limit` clause for pagination like:

```js
    const elements = await ElementsModel.findAll({
      limit: 10,
      offset: 0,
      attributes: {
        include: [[Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("related.id")), "related_total"]]
      },
      include: [
        {
          model: RelatedModel,
          attributes: [],
        }
      ],
      group: ['elements.id']
    });
```

And the query breaks and is not working anymore because of the combination of the included field and the `limit` clause, generating an invalid query like:

```sql
SELECT `elements`.* 
FROM (
  SELECT `elements`.`id`, `elements`.`type`, COUNT(`related`.`coupon_id`) AS `related_total` 
  FROM `elements` AS `elements` GROUP BY `elements`.`id` LIMIT 0, 20
) AS `elements` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `related` AS `related` ON `elements`.`id` = `related`.`elements_id`;
```

There is some way to handle this with Sequelize?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use `limit` and `offset` options properly you need to use a subquery with `Sequelize.literal` instead of `Sequelize.fn` and remove the `include` and `group` options at all.

```js
const elements = await ElementsModel.findAll({
      limit: 10,
      offset: 0,
      attributes: {
        include: [
  // correct a table name and fields if needed
  [Sequelize.literal("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Related where Related.elementId=Elements.id)"), "related_total"]
      ]
      },
    });
```

Comment: There is a typo in the included attribute code, but yes, using the literal subquery solves the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Just a note if your table name consists of 2 words you need to escape it. e.g. it it's `ElementsTable` you need to write  `"ElementsTable".id` in the `Sequalize.literal(..`.

Comment: Escaping character depends on a certain DB so it's up to a developer either use it or not depending on a table name and DBMS.